# Grabbing Certain Parts of XML Stored in DB - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, database

In my database I have a column that stores XML data, the database items are accessed through my model. However I need to be able to access specific items within the XML column, and convert them into a string to be used on my web page, what's the best way of doing this?

**Example:**

```
<DATAROW AgreementNumber="0000000" LoanAmount="£0.00" LoanTerm="20"
Title="Miss" FirstName="Joe" LastName="Bloggs"/>
```

Comment: Well, what items do you need to grab?

Comment: @DavidG The example XML is a lot smaller, let's say however I want to grab FirstName and LastName

Comment: Did you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You mean something like this? `SELECT xmlColumn.value('(/DATAROW/@FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS FirstName, xmlColumn.value('(/DATAROW/@LastName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS LastName`?